# Execute parallel testing based on JUnit category

Tags: java, maven, junit, parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin

I use Junit 4.8 and maven 3,
I have tests which can be executed in parallel but others which can't because it access to an Oracle database. 
I would like to use Junit categories for indicating the tests which can be "parallelized" and others and launching the tests by using a simple 'mvn test'. It that's possible ?
My maven configuration would be something like that i think :

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12</version>
  <configuration>
     <groups>com.soft.Parallelizable</groups>
     <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
     <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
     <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx512m</argLine>
     <parallel>classes</parallel>
     <threadCount>30</threadCount>
   </configuration>
   <configuration>
     <groups>com.soft.NotParallelizable</groups>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Of course it doesn't work but it's just to show you what i would like do.
If somebody has an idea :)

Comment: Maven surefire is responsible for unit tests which should always be able to run parallelized where as integration tests which the maven-failsafe-plugin is responsible for are might be parallelized. It sounds you are mixing unit and integration tests.

Comment: A good usecase for this might be to test DAO objects synchronously while having other tests which mock the DAO's run in parallel. I would be interested in a solution to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

After 2.18 version there's an option for this:

> Since of Surefire 2.18, you can apply the JCIP annotation
>   @net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe

you can read it [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) 
it worked for me